# Soundcloud Java Api wrapper duplicate file error

Tags: java, android, gradle

I used the java Api wrapper from [Soundcloud java Api wrapper](https://github.com/soundcloud/java-api-wrapper) ,
in my app, i added the JAR file to my project and included it as a library

I added this code to my activity

```
    ApiWrapper api = new ApiWrapper(getClient_ID(),getClient_Secret(),null,null);
```

and this is the error from my Gradle

```html
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
 File1: C:\Users\Devandrin\Documents\Projects\team25\Android\Eternal_Vibes\libs\java-api-wrapper-1.2.0-all.jar
 File2: C:\Users\Devandrin\Documents\Projects\team25\Android\Eternal_Vibes\libs\java-api-wrapper-1.2.0-all.jar
 File3: C:\Users\Devandrin\Documents\Projects\team25\Android\Eternal_Vibes\libs\java-api-wrapper-1.2.0-all.jar
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? or how to exclude those files?

Answer (score 0):

In your Android DSL, simply add the following:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude "META-INF/LICENSE"
    }
}
```

**Docs:** https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html

Comment: Throws me this error now

Error:(23, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_1e69jjkzxvvwaeoi58do9f5ne$_run_closure3@617fd8cf] on root project 'Eternal_Vibes' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Devandrin\Documents\Projects\team25\Android\Eternal_Vibes\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: Are you not using the Android plugin? Please post both of your build.gradle files.

Comment: I've found an alternative way by using a webview with the raw api
Thank you for the help bro